# Difference between `throw new Error` and `throw Error`?

Tags: javascript

Are there any drawbacks of throwing Errors without the `new` keyword?

```js
throw new Error('Something went wrong');

/* vs */

throw Error('Something went wrong');
```

Answer (score 11):

They are exactly the same, as guaranteed [by the specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-error-constructor):

> **19.5.1** The Error Constructor
>
> The Error constructor:
>
> ...
>
> creates and initializes a new Error object when called as a function rather than as a constructor. Thus the function call `Error(…)` is equivalent to the object creation expression `new Error(…)` with the same arguments.